# Use PHP Variable In str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this code

```
$html = str_replace( '<a','<a class="name"', $html );
```

And i need to add a variable like this to the code

```
$html = str_replace( '<a','<a class="$var"', $html );
```

But this doesn't work.

**Edit :** Is it possible to do this using sprintf?

Any ideas on how i can do this :

Comment: Try like this `$html = str_replace( '<a',"<a class=\"{$var}\"", $html );` - use double quots. Also you can concatenate strings `$html = str_replace( '<a','<a class="'. $var . '"', $html );`

Comment: How about using sprintf?

Comment: sprintf too, any expression that will return string.

Comment: How do i use sprintf to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. Here are two:

```
$html = str_replace('<a', '<a class="' . $var . '"', $html);
```

and

```
$html = str_replace("<a", "<a class=\"$var\"", $html);
```

The backslash in front of the `"` is called a 'escape'. It means the `"` will be left as it is, and not be interpreted as an ending of a string constant.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using single quotes, variables are not filled. This behavior only exists if you have double quotes. This would work for example:

```
$html = str_replace( '<a','<a class="' . $var . '"', $html );
```

Here the `.` is used to 'concatenate' the strings, in other words glue them together.

You could also use a different approach where you make the quotes around the class name single quotes:

```
$html = str_replace( '<a',"<a class='$var'", $html );
```

As said, these are double quotes. This means that the variable can be escaped in quotes now.

Either of them will work, it is whatever you really desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the string you are replacing with in double quotes and use `$var` without quotes:

```
$html = str_replace( '<a',"<a class=$var", $html );
```